# Laravel: rota com parâmetros

Tags: php, laravel, url, rotas

Tenho um sistema escolar com uma tela de chamadas onde tem um botão que abre um modal com um formulário para escolher a turma e a data (`chamadas/index`). Esse formulário vai redirecionar para uma tela com a lista de alunos da turma escolhida para lançar a chamada no dia selecionado anteriormente.

Como eu devo montar uma rota que aceite receber algo parecido com `chamadas?turma=1&data=21-08-2017` ?

Mesmo que exista uma forma em que os parâmetros não apareçam na url pra mim já serve.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

O mais simples possivel, ***exemplo***:

```
Route::get('chamadas/{turma}/{data}', "ChamadasController@index");
```

na sua classe `controller`

```
class ChamadasController 
{
    public function index($turma, $data)
    {
         // ... code
    }
}
```

a sua `url` seria isso:

```
http://site.com/chamadas/1/21-08-2017
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)
- [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Não funcionou :( Mostra rota inexistente

Comment: @Matheus a sua rota é um `link` ou um `post`? Essa mensagem é porque está fazendo algo que a aplicação não está configurado corretamente, gostaria que editasse a sua pergunta e conte o que você fez... ??? Se possivel coloque todas as rotas e qual rota está usando ???